# How much does it usually cost to host a small Wordpress blog on Amazon?

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting, wordpress, amazon-web-services

How much does it usually cost to host a small Wordpress blog on Amazon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: S3 is only for storing static (unchanging) content like images or text files. Wordpress doesn't fit this setup - it rerenders the page every time you view it, so you really want to be comparing your current MediaTemple setup to Amazon EC2, which lets you rent a computer by the hour.

The smallest instance size is a Micro, which provides 613MB RAM - more than enough to run a small Wordpress installation.

Instances are $0.02/hour, or about $15/month assuming you want your blog to be up and running 24/7. Micro instances come with no disk space and need an EBS volume to have a place to store your data ($0.10/GB/month) and bandwidth is extra, so assume all together somewhere just south of $20/month.

You can get cheaper if you're willing to prepay for a reserved instance - for example, $82 up front lets you pay $0.007/hour for the instance, which over 3 years lowers the instance hour cost to under $10/month. You'd still need disk + bandwith, so the absolute cheapest this way would be about $15/month.

Remember, however, with EC2 all you get is the raw resources. With great power comes great responsibility. There's no hand-holding on getting things running, maintaining security updates, dealing with machine crashes etc. That's probably a large part of what a company like MediaTemple is providing, and by switching to EC2 for a few buck less you'll be losing that.

Comment: +1 for an accurate depiction... however... a sly admin could host his WordPress instance locally for editing and such, then use S3 as a reverse proxy (assuming comments and interactive features are disabled or forwarded to the working WordPress instance)

Comment: @danlefree: You're absolutely right. I'd consider doing it just for the challenge, but honestly if you're going the static-files-on-S3 route there are much better tools than Wordpress. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[4sysops](http://4sysops.com) has a series of posts on [Amazon hosting](http://4sysops.com/archives/series/one-year-amazon-ec2/) for the blog he runs.  Worth reading through them.  Goes over the positives, and negatives, as well as costs.

Answer (score 0):

A AWS micro instance (the smallest they have) is sufficient for your blog.

$0.085 per hour => $62/month

Comment: A blog with 50 subs for 62 dollars a month?  Wow... that's much too expensive by far, from where I'm sitting.

Comment: This is incorrect. Micro instances are only $0.02/hour. The $0.085/hour is for a small instance, which has 1.7GB RAM, per-instance ephemeral disk space, and more dedicate access to the CPU, albeit less burstability.

Answer (score 0):

They also have a free offering for one year: http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Can Amazon S3 be used for hosting PHP scripts or not?

Comment: Yes, you can use either Windows or Linux and both support PHP

Comment: Wait, S3? Not EC2?

Comment: You can *host* scripts on S3, as in you can store the files there and download them (the scripts, not the web pages you want them to generate), but you can't *execute* them, as S3 is purely a storage service and offers no way to execute code.